# JSON GSON - Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, rest, gson

When I try to receive a JSON, Gson shows the following message error:

> Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Actually at the line `System.out.println(jsonCep.toString());` I can see the right JSON. Here's the JSON printed:

`{"status":{"code":200,"message":"Ok"},"data":\[\],"page":{"next":"https://sandbox-api.arquivei.com.br/v1/nfe/received?cnpj%5C%5B0%5C%5D=34174654000153&cursor=0&limit=50%22,%22previous%22:%22https://sandbox-api.arquivei.com.br/v1/nfe/received?cnpj%5C%5B0%5C%5D=34174654000153&cursor=0&limit=50%22%7D,%22count%22:0,%22signature%22:%224f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945"}`

But when I try to send JSON to an object, it shows the error. Here is the line where I try to receive a JSON converted:

```
UsuarioPessoa user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonCep.toString(), UsuarioPessoa.class);
```

Here is my full code:

```java
public void pesquisaCode() {
    try {
        String code="34174654000153";
        String apikey = "69087091f4d28d29e5c2d326831c86bfc7903634";
        String apiID="b79cbfedaf0d9b0be1a3a2d7263fdc61c94e2311";
        URL url = new URL("https://sandbox-api.arquivei.com.br/v1/nfe/received?cnpj[]="+code+"");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-API-KEY", apikey);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-API-ID", apiID);
        ((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        String cep="";
        StringBuilder jsonCep = new StringBuilder();
        while((cep = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonCep.append(cep);
        }
        System.out.println(jsonCep.toString());
        UsuarioPessoa user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonCep.toString(), UsuarioPessoa.class);
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would like to receive in my object the following result. Here is the result in postman.

```json
{
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Ok"
  },
  "data": [
    
  ],
  "page": {
    "next": "https:\/\/sandbox-api.arquivei.com.br\/v1\/nfe\/received?cnpj[0]=34174654000153&cursor=0&limit=50",
    "previous": "https:\/\/sandbox-api.arquivei.com.br\/v1\/nfe\/received?cnpj[0]=34174654000153&cursor=0&limit=50"
  },
  "count": 0,
  "signature": "4f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945"
}
```

Comment: if the parser is fine, it might jsut be your pojo

Comment: What's `UsuarioPessoa`?